# javascript/jQuery: animate() does not run but callback does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to debug a callback function I have written that fires when certain links on my page are clicked. For a while, everything worked fine, but it was buggy, and so I began trying to debug my callback. Here is the current state of my code:

```
function doStuff() {

    var container = $("#content-container");

    var ch = container.height();

    container.animate({
        top : '-=' + ch + 'px'
    }, 500, function() {console.log('animating');});
}

$(".content-link").live("click", function(){
    doStuff();
    return false;
});
```

The animation moves the `#content-container` element off the top of the page. It used to be the case that this animation worked fine. However, when I replaced the callback to `animate()` with `console.log()` in order to form the code shown, the animation stopped working, but a message is still logged to the console. Why isn't the animation running even though the callback is being fired?

Comment: `live` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.6 and removed from jQuery 1.9. Use `on`.

Comment: what's the value of `ch`?

Comment: when I log `ch` to the console, it's the height of the container, around 2200 px. if I log `container.html()` to the console, then I get the html that I expect that element to contain. So `container` is definitely referencing the right thing.

Comment: Could it be that value of container.height() and container top are the same?

Comment: @AlexeyAza then it should still animate the `top` by 2200 px upwards

Comment: Is the element positioned (`position:absolute`)?

Comment: Alexey, no, that is not the case, as I can run this function on different pages with different container heights without changing the result, and the only thing I changed to make this code break was I changed the callback of `container.animate()`, nothing else.

Comment: Is the container in position absolute, fixed of relative?

Comment: can you show the working code?

Comment: Jan, no, it is not `position: absolute;`, but like I said before, that should not be a problem as the animation itself used to work.

Comment: Complete with fiddles for both, ideally: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @jayhendren if the element isn't positioned, its `top` property will have no effect

Comment: hold on, I'll get a test page up soon

Comment: ok, test page is up: http://jay-hendren.appspot.com/ try clicking on things (with `class="content-link"` to be specific); it *should* make the content of the page move off the top of the window. At least, it used to.

Comment: the `position` might be the culprit. testing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that you're using `live` when you should be using `bind`. As far as I know, `live` was removed in jquery 1.9.

```
$(".content-link").bind("click", function(){
    doStuff();
    return false;
});
```

Other than that, the only other thing I think might be wrong is that you need to have a position property set for the container class otherwise the top won't have any effect.

[Fiddle link with working code](http://jsfiddle.net/QsEJk/5/)

Comment: no, no, no. Read the comments. This has nothing to do with the issue. I've changed `live` to `on` as suggested, which changed nothing.

Comment: @jayhendren Look at the fiddle link I've included - the code does work.

Comment: You're right, and I changed `bind` to `live` in your fiddle which broke the code, but this isn't the culprit in my code (I think I have an old version of jQuery).

Comment: @jayhendren Well I've shown you an example of the code working with nothing more than the bind change and a `position:relative` in the css. If that doesn't work for you, then there must be something else about your markup or css that is causing the problem.

Comment: well since you are technically correct and your answer is the only one besides mine, I'm accepting your answer even though Jan Dvorak pointed out the `position` problem in the comments first, which was the answer in this case. :P

Comment: @jayhendren Sorry, I didn't realise Jan Dvorak had already given you that answer in the comments. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` needed to be set for the `container` element in order for it to be animated. Thanks to Jan Dvorak for pointing this out. I still don't know why things worked previously even though the only thing I changed was javascript, not my style sheet or anything...